# select data based on a string criteria python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, startswith

I have a large database in which I want to select all the columns that meet a certain criteria:

My data looks like the following:

```
Name  a  b  c 
target-01  5196     24     24  
target-02  5950    150    150 
target-03  5598     50     50 
object-01  6558     44     -1 
object-02  6190     60     60
```

I want to select all the data whose `Name` starts with `target`.

So the selected `df` would be:

```
target-01  5196     24     24  
target-02  5950    150    150 
target-03  5598     50     50
```

I am reading the data using:

```
data = pd.read_csv('catalog.txt', sep = '\s+', header = None, skiprows =1 )
```

How can I select the data I want?

Comment: If you would like to apply further filtering of your data, you may take a look at the panda library: http://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[df.Name.str.startswith('target')])
        Name     a    b    c
0  target-01  5196   24   24
1  target-02  5950  150  150
2  target-03  5598   50   50
```

Another solution with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
print (df[df.Name.str.contains(r'^target')])
        Name     a    b    c
0  target-01  5196   24   24
1  target-02  5950  150  150
2  target-03  5598   50   50
```

Last solution with [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)

print (df.filter(regex=r'^target', axis=0))
              a    b    c
Name                     
target-01  5196   24   24
target-02  5950  150  150
target-03  5598   50   50

print (df.filter(regex=r'^target', axis=0).reset_index())
        Name     a    b    c
0  target-01  5196   24   24
1  target-02  5950  150  150
2  target-03  5598   50   50
```